# Win 7 can no longer see shares on Win 10 Home network

Tags: windows-7, networking

Home network: Win 10 and Win 7. Have set both to share folders, made sure network discovery is on. For a long time i could move or read files in either direction. Now Win 7 cannot even see Win 10 on network.10 can still access files on 7.

Sometimes i have to cold boot router and both PCs after a while,since I leave everything on 24/7. But now that doesn't refresh the network either.

I presume Win 10 upgrades are behind this?

I had this problem before, the AT&T tech had me set up static IPs for each computer and this fixed the problem. Now Win 7 again cannot even locate Win 10 on the network.

Answer (score 0):

A while back, Windows 10 supported Home Group and no longer does. So you need to use traditional file sharing. Make sure (Network and Sharing Centre for all computers) that Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing as well as. passwords required settings are all ON. You will probably need to set up the Windows 7 userid and password on the Windows 7 machine. All the machines should be in the same Workgroup. Restart all the computers and test

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102652/discussion-on-answer-by-john-win-7-can-no-longer-see-shares-on-win-10-home-netwo).